# ReflectionTypeLoadException when trying to load types from system assemblies

Tags: .net, reflection

This is not a problem that I am experiencing on my own dev machine or have ever been able to reproduce, but I've been getting a lot of crash logs with this problem from end-users, and I have no idea what's causing it.

The problem is that, for a small percentage of users, when my application calls `Assembly.GetTypes()` on some System assemblies (always System assemblies built-in to .NET, but different assemblies for different users), it crashes with a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` with a seemingly-garbled message:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ð½ Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð±Ð¾Ð»ÐµÐµ Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÑˆÐµÐ½Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ‚Ð¸Ð¿Ð¾Ð². ÐžÐ±Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÑ ÑŒ Ðº Ñ Ð²Ð¾Ð¹Ñ Ñ‚Ð²Ñƒ LoaderExceptions Ð´Ð»Ñ  Ð¿Ð¾Ð»ÑƒÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ  Ð´Ð¾Ð¿Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð¸Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½Ñ‹Ñ… Ñ Ð²ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð¹.
    Ð² System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
    Ð² System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
    [my code]
```

Printing out the `LoaderExceptions` property always points to a System assembly as the culprit, but does not provide any additional useful information. (And again, the specific assembly seems to change from user to user.) Here's an example of the output I get when printing out all the loader exceptions retrieved from a single `ReflectionTypeLoadException`:

```
Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ñ ÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÐºÑƒ "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñƒ Ð¸Ð· Ð¸Ñ… Ð·Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹. Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð».
Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ñ ÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÐºÑƒ "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñƒ Ð¸Ð· Ð¸Ñ… Ð·Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹. Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð».
Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ñ ÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÐºÑƒ "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñƒ Ð¸Ð· Ð¸Ñ… Ð·Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹. Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð».
Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ñ ÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÐºÑƒ "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñƒ Ð¸Ð· Ð¸Ñ… Ð·Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹. Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð».
Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°Ð»Ð¾Ñ ÑŒ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ñ€ÑƒÐ·Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð» Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð±Ð¾Ñ€ÐºÑƒ "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Ð»Ð¸Ð±Ð¾ Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñƒ Ð¸Ð· Ð¸Ñ… Ð·Ð°Ð²Ð¸Ñ Ð¸Ð¼Ð¾Ñ Ñ‚ÐµÐ¹. Ð Ðµ ÑƒÐ´Ð°ÐµÑ‚Ñ Ñ  Ð½Ð°Ð¹Ñ‚Ð¸ ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ð°Ð½Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ„Ð°Ð¹Ð».
```

Again, the text is strangely garbled. Any idea what's going on? Any idea how to debug this?

Here's the code from my program that calls `Assembly.GetTypes()`:

```
        foreach(Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Type[] types;
            try
            {
                types = assembly.GetTypes();
            }
            catch(ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Error getting types from assembly: " + assembly.FullName);
                Logger.LogError("LoaderExceptions:");
                foreach(Exception ex2 in ex.LoaderExceptions)
                    Logger.LogError("\t" + ex2.Message);
                throw;
            }

            // Do stuff with the loaded types...
        }
```

Comment: It is a memory corruption problem, not caused by any code you wrote.  Assuming your code does not do anything dangerous with the unsafe keyword or pinvoke.  Best you can do is get the IT staff of these users together so they can compare notes and find out what they have in common.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, I certainly can't rule out that my application (or the libraries it uses) aren't causing memory corruption, so I guess now I get to try to figure out whether that's the case. Thanks!